# unknown field solr drupal module

Tags: drupal, solr

```
Indexing failed on one of the following entity ids: node/2 
"400" Status: ERROR: [doc=l8febs/node/2] unknown field 'language': ERROR: [doc=l8febs/node/2] unknown field 'language'


Error 400 ERROR: [doc=l8febs/node/2] unknown field 'language'

HTTP ERROR 400
Problem accessing /solr/update. Reason:
ERROR: [doc=l8febs/node/2] unknown field 'language'Powered by Jetty://
```

I am wondering what is the problem. My `schema.xml` file does not have a field named language, will that solve the problem? I have never needed this?

schema.xml

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="name" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/> 
<!-- entity_id is the numeric object ID, e.g. Node ID, File ID -->
<field name="entity_id"  type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<!-- entity_type is 'node', 'file', 'user', or some other Drupal object type -->
<field name="entity_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<!-- bundle is a node type, or as appropriate for other entity types -->
<field name="bundle" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="bundle_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="text" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<field name="site" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="hash" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="url" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<!-- label is the default field for a human-readable string for this entity (e.g. the  title of a node) -->
<field name="label" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true"  omitNorms="true"/>
<!-- The string version of the title is used for sorting -->
<copyField source="label" dest="sort_label"/>
<!-- content is the default field for full text search - dump crap here -->
<field name="content" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true"/>
<field name="teaser" type="text" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="language" type="text_en" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<field name="path" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="path_alias" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

The apache solr 3.2 and the schema.xml is from the apaache solr integration module for drupal 7

solrconfig.xml is

```
<requestHandler name="dismax" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="defType">dismax</str>
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <bool name="omitHeader">true</bool>
 </lst>
</requestHandler>

<!-- Note how you can register the same handler multiple times with
    different names (and different init parameters)
-->
 <requestHandler name="drupal" class="solr.SearchHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="defType">dismax</str>
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
     <bool name="omitHeader">true</bool>
     <float name="tie">0.01</float>
     <str name="pf">
         content^2.0
     </str>
    <int name="ps">15</int>
      <!-- Abort any searches longer than 4 seconds -->
      <!-- <int name="timeAllowed">4000</int>  -->
     <str name="mm">1</str>
    <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>

    <!-- example highlighter config, enable per-query with hl=true -->
      <str name="hl">true</str>
      <str name="hl.fl">content</str>
      <int name="hl.snippets">3</int>
      <str name="hl.mergeContiguous">true</str>
      <!-- instructs Solr to return the field itself if no query terms are
    found -->
     <str name="f.content.hl.alternateField">teaser</str>
     <str name="f.content.hl.maxAlternateFieldLength">256</str>
     <!-- JS: I wasn't getting good results here... I'm turning off for now
      because I was getting periods (.) by themselves at the beginning of
      snippets and don't feel like debugging anymore.  Without the regex is
      faster too -->
     <!--<str name="f.content.hl.fragmenter">regex</str>--> <!-- defined below -->

     <!-- By default, don't spell check -->
      <str name="spellcheck">false</str>
      <!-- Defaults for the spell checker when used -->
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
      <!--  The number of suggestions to return -->
     <str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Comment: what fields are you submitting to solr? what version?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want fields, you can simple ignore the fields to prevent them causing error. e.g.

Define a ignored field type :-

```
<fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" class="solr.StrField" />
```

And define a Dynamic field :-

```
<dynamicField name="some regex to capture all unwanted fields"  type="ignored"/>
```